# Getting this Error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/manage.py' in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am encountering a PermissionError when trying to run the docker compose run command for creating a Django project. The error message is as follows :-

```
docker compose run --rm app sh -c "django-admin startproject myproject ."
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                   docker:desktop-linux 
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                   docker:desktop-linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 21, in handle
    super().handle("project", project_name, target, **options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 205, in handle
    with open(new_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as new_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/manage.py'
.
.
.
```

And this is my Dockerfile :-

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app



ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER app
```

.
.

and this is my docker-compose.yml file :-

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    image: my-django-image
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
```

i tried few of the solutions but nothing worked..
I'm using Zorin OS

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is overwriting the container's `/app` directory with content from the host, which can lead to permission problems like this and otherwise lead to hard-to-reproduce trouble.  Does deleting that line help?  You seem to have forgotten the `CMD` from the Dockerfile, what is the main command the container should run?

Answer (score 0):

This creates the `/app` folder inside the container, and it is owned by root:

```
COPY ./app /app
```

Then you change to another user:

```
USER app
```

... which tries to execute the command `django-admin startproject myproject .` but it does not have permission to write to the `/app` folder, and so you get the error.

Why are you trying to run that command inside the container anyway?  The usual practice is to create the files locally and then copy them into the container, rather than creating them dynamically inside the container.

Comment: then please tell me how to give permission to write the /app folder I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The Error  is likely related to file permissions within the Docker container. It indicates a `PermissionError` when attempting to create a file `/app/manage.py` inside that container. Now to solve this Please Update your Dockerfile to set proper permissions for the `/app` directory and its contents. You can do this by adding the following lines to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app

# Set proper permissions
RUN chown -R app /app

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER app
```

This line `RUN chown -R app /app` ensures that the `app` user has ownership of the `/app` directory and its contents.

After applying above changes to your Dockerfile, rebuild the Docker image via

```
docker-compose build
```

Then Run Docker Compose Again

`docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django-admin startproject myproject ."`

After that Django project should be created inside the container without encountering permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the ownership. You can do so by modifying the COPY command in the Dockerfile. You want to keep the amount of layers minimal, so I suggest incorporating the 'chown' into the COPY command.

```
COPY --chown=app ./app /app
```